# How do I increase the size of the plot in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: visualization, data-visualization, seaborn

I am trying to plot a histogram using Seaborn in python. I am using the sns.distplot function to pllot the histogram. I want to make my chart a little wider. How do I do that? I tried the help functionality in python but that did not help. Thanks

```
sns.set_style("dark")

ax = sns.distplot(data["Trip_distance"], bins= 50, kde= False, axlabel= "Trip Distance")

ax.set_ylabel('Count')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer. The first line in the code below.

```
sns.set(rc={"figure.figsize": (8, 4)})
sns.set_style("dark")
ax = sns.distplot(data["Trip_distance"], bins= 50, kde= False, axlabel= "Trip Distance")
ax.set_ylabel('Count')
ax.set_title("Histogram of Trip Distance")
```

Comment: Does this however affect the current cell, or all subsequent cells?

Answer (score 1):

Another method would be to create the figure and axes prior to plotting to them.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))
sns.distplot(data["Trip_distance"], bins= 50, kde= False, axlabel= "Trip Distance", ax= ax)
ax.set_ylabel('Count')
ax.set_title("Histogram of Trip Distance")
```